# Smooth extension of a function with negative second derivative, satisfying differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a real smooth function such that $g(0) = 0$(and nullifies nowhere else), and that for some $t_0>0$, $\max{g} = g(t_0)$, $g'(t_0) = 0$. Suppose $g\geq0$, $g'' \leq 0$ for $0\leq t\leq t_0$.

Now, suppose a function $y:[0,t_0]\to\mathbb{R}$, such that $y(t) = g(t)$ for $0\leq t\leq t_0$. Define $y_{max} = \max{g}$. Also, suppose that the following equation holds:
$$
{y'}^2 = f(y)
$$
where $f$ is a smooth function, $f(y) > 0$ for all $y<y_{max}$, $f(y_{max}) =0$.

I want to smoothly extend $y$ to the interval $[0,2t_0]$, such that $y(2t_0) = 0$, $y'' \leq 0$, and the differential equation above will still hold. Is the ***only*** way to do this, is by setting $y(t) = y(2t_0-t)$ for $t_0\leq t\leq 2t_0$? That is, is it a unique solution for the above conditions to project $y$ in $[0,t_0]$ around $t = t_0$?